# Caching issue in Android Retrofit

Tags: android, caching, retrofit, okhttp

I'm trying to get caching to work with Retrofit with no luck, and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Using:

**build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.5.+'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.5.+'
```

**Example Call**

```
@Headers("Cache-Control: public, max-age=640000, s-maxage=640000 , max-stale=10000000")
@GET("/articles/{article}")
public void getArticle(
    @Path("article") String id,
    Callback<Article> cb
);
```

**Building the API**

```
File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
cache = null;
try {
    cache = new HttpResponseCache(cacheDir, 10 * 1024 * 1024);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setResponseCache(cache);
OkClient okClient = new OkClient(okHttpClient);

api = new RestAdapter.Builder()
   .setEndpoint(TestAPI.BASE_URL)
   .setRequestInterceptor( ... only adding path params ... )
   .setClient(okClient)
   .build()
   .create(TestAPI.class);
```

The call works, the only issue is actually getting it to cache... I'm checking against  cache.getHitCount() after I make my calls to check if there was anything that cached, and it always turns up as 0.

Comment: OkHttp automatically process cache based on [HTTP standart](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html). I would suggest to print logs and see if your server correctly forms Cache-control header and indicates that request could be cached on client. Most likely you do not need to tweak headers on client, but config server instead.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with a different solution out of another necessity, but I hope your comment helps lead others to the right solution!

Comment: By any chance, did you return back to this issue and solved it? I have got a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467416/retrofit-cache-control-never-included-in-response but for Retrofit 1.6.0

Comment: Hey @zatziky, I ended up needing a more flexible cache solution for another reason, so I wrote a Cache Library that fit my needs called [CREAM](https://github.com/carrot/cream).  There's some examples in there to get you started if you wanted to go that route.  If you have any questions about it shoot me an email (on my stackoverflow profile).

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
public InterfaceRequests  getProductListAdapter(final AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity) {
        File httpCacheDirectory = new File(appCompatActivity.getCacheDir(), "responses");

        Cache cache = null;
        try {
            cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, 10 * 1024 * 1024);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("OKHttp", "Could not create http cache", e);
        }

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        if (cache != null) {
            okHttpClient.setCache(cache);
        }

        InterfaceRequests getReportList = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(InterfaceRequests.aPIBaseURL)
                .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
                .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                        request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;versions=1");
                        if (CheckForInternetConnection.isNetworkAvailable(appCompatActivity)) {
                            int maxAge = 60; // read from cache for 1 minute
                            request.addHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + maxAge);
                        } else {
                            int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 28; // tolerate 4-weeks stale
                            request.addHeader("Cache-Control",
                                    "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .build()
                .create(InterfaceRequests.class);

        return getReportList;
    }
```