# Retrofit: cache-control never included in response

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

no matter what I do I can never see the header **cache-control** in the response.

**Settings**

- retrofit 1.6.0
- okHttp 1.6.0
- okHttp-urlConnection 1.6.0
- gson 2.2.4
- Android 4.0+

**1. Configuration**

**1.1 RestAdapter with my OkHttpClient**

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
Cache cache = new Cache(getCacheDir(), 1024);
okHttpClient.setCache(cache);

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(URL)
            .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
            .setLogLevel(LogLevel.HEADERS)
            .build();
```

**1.2 RestAdapter with the default OkHttpClient**
Here, when debugging I could see that the client has **cache=null;**

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(URL)
            .setLogLevel(LogLevel.HEADERS)
            .build();
```

**2 Log**

For the both configurations the logs are the same.

**2.1 REQUEST**

> 06-28 13:24:05.601: D/Retrofit(1581): ---> HTTP GET myUri
>
> 06-28 13:24:05.601: D/Retrofit(1581): Cache-Control: public,
> max-age=640000
>
> 06-28 13:24:05.601: D/Retrofit(1581): ---> END HTTP (no body)

**2.2 RESPONSE**

> 06-28 13:24:05.701: D/Retrofit(1581): <--- HTTP 200 myUri (102ms)
>
> 06-28 13:24:05.701: D/Retrofit(1581): : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> 06-28 13:24:05.701: D/Retrofit(1581): Connection: keep-alive
>
> 06-28 13:24:05.701: D/Retrofit(1581): Content-Type: text/html
>
> 06-28 13:24:05.701: D/Retrofit(1581): Date: Sat, 28 Jun 2014 13:24:01
> GMT
>
> 06-28 13:24:05.701: D/Retrofit(1581): OkHttp-Received-Millis:
> 1403961845708
>
> 06-28 13:24:05.701: D/Retrofit(1581): OkHttp-Response-Source: NETWORK
> 200
>
> 06-28 13:24:05.701: D/Retrofit(1581): OkHttp-Sent-Millis:
> 1403961845680
>
> 06-28 13:24:05.701: D/Retrofit(1581): Server: nginx/1.6.0
>
> 06-28 13:24:05.701: D/Retrofit(1581): Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> 06-28 13:24:05.701: D/Retrofit(1581): Vary: Accept-Encoding
>
> 06-28 13:24:05.701: D/Retrofit(1581): X-Powered-By:
> PHP/5.5.12-1~dotdeb.1
>
> 06-28 13:24:05.701: D/Retrofit(1581): <--- END HTTP (-1-byte body)

**EDIT 03/07/2014**

I noticed that in this question [Retrofit+OkHttp is ok when sending GET requests but gives SocketTimetout when sending POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874303/retrofitokhttp-is-ok-when-sending-get-requests-but-gives-sockettimetout-when-se) the asker gets "cache-control" in response.

> 04-11 18:00:41.291: D/Retrofit(16390): ---> HTTP GET url
>
> 04-11 18:00:41.291: D/Retrofit(16390): ---> END HTTP (0-byte body)
>
> 04-11 18:00:42.008: D/Retrofit(16390): <--- HTTP 200 url (716ms)
>
> 04-11 18:00:42.015: D/Retrofit(16390): : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> **04-11 18:00:42.015: D/Retrofit(16390): Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate**

Still cannot solve this issue neither in emulators nor in a real device though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ME STUPID, we didn't properly setup cache on our backend!